# Solve Equations using Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, complex

Good day. I have a question of how to get the algebraic expressions for $a$, real part $b$ (denoted $Re(b)$), and imaginary part $b$ (denoted $Im(b)$).
Let's say $a$ is a real number and $b$ is a complex number.
I have three equations as below:

$$a ^ 2 = X,\quad(a + b)^2 = Y,\quad(a + bi)^2 = Z,$$

where $X, Y, Z$ are symbols, and $i$ is imaginary part of $1i$. I tried to solve above equations to get $a$ and $Re(b)$, $Im(b)$ in terms of symbols $X, Y, Z$.

I tried to solve above equations by hand. Let $$b = u + vi$$. So we have:

$$a = \sqrt X, \quad (a + (u + vi))^2 = Y,\quad (a + (u + vi)i)^2 = Z, $$

Then I stuck at this step. May I ask if we want to use Mathematica to solve above equations. That is, get u and v in terms of X, Y, Z. How should I do? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is the value of $x$ determines the values of $a, u, v, y, z$, within a sign.

```
eqns = {a^2 == x, (a + b)^2 == y, (a + b*I)^2 == z};
cons = {0 < x, {a, x, y, z} ∈ Reals};
Solve[Join[eqns, cons], {a, b, y, z}]
```

[image]

But there is no solution when $x, y,z$ are independent, real parameters.

```
Solve[Join[eqns, cons], {a, b}]         (*   { }   *)
```

**To see why this happens**, look at the equations one at a time.  The first equation has two real solutions for $a$, provided $0<x$

```
sola = Solve[a^2 == x, a, Reals];
Simplify[sola, 0 < x]   (*  {{a -> -Sqrt[x]}, {a -> Sqrt[x]}}  *)
```

The second equation has two solutions for $b$.  Each solution for $b$ is in terms of either of the solutions for $a$.

```
solb = Solve[(a + b)^2 == y, b]   (*  {{b -> -a - Sqrt[y]}, {b -> -a + Sqrt[y]}}  *)
```

To determine $u$ and $v$, there are four cases to consider, four combinations of the 2 solutions for $a$ and the 2 solutions for $b$.

**Case 1:**

```
case1 = Join[First[solb], First[sola]];
{u1, v1} = Simplify[ReIm[b] /. case1, 0 < x]

(*  {Sqrt[x] - Re[Sqrt[y]], -Im[Sqrt[y]]}  *)
```

Note that the value of $z$ has not been used.  Let's see if we can find a $z$ that is compatible with $0<x$ and $y\in \text{Reals}$:

```
z1 = Simplify[(a + b*I)^2 /. case1, 0 < x];
solz = Reduce[{Im[z1] == 0, 0 < x, Im[y] == 0}, y];
Simplify[{
  z1 /. ToRules[First[Last[solz]]],
  z1 /. ToRules[Last[Last[solz]]]}, 0 < x]           (*  {-x, x}  *)
```

So, in case 1 we get two possible solutions for $z$ in terms of $x$.

**Case 2:**
In the second case there is no solution for $z$.

```
case2 = Join[Last[solb], First[sola]];
{u2, v2} = Simplify[ReIm[b] /. case2, 0 < x];

z2 = Simplify[(a + b*I)^2 //. case2, 0 < x];
solz = Reduce[{Im[z2] == 0, 0 < x, Im[y] == 0}, y]      (*  False  *)
```

**Case 3:**
In the third case we get the same two solutions for $z$ as in Case 1.

```
case3 = Join[Last[solb], Last[sola]];
{u3, v3} = Simplify[ReIm[b] /. case3, 0 < x];

z3 = Simplify[(a + b*I)^2 //. case3, 0 < x];
solz = Reduce[{Im[z3] == 0, 0 < x, Im[y] == 0}, y];
Simplify[{
  z3 /. ToRules[First[Last[solz]]],
  z3 /. ToRules[Last[Last[solz]]]}, 0 < x]             (*  {-x, x}  *)
```

**Case 4:**
In the fourth case there is no solution for $z$.

**Conclusion**

When we specify $a, x \in \text{Reals}$, there are only certain values of $y$ and $z$ that will give solutions.  There is no solution when $x,y,z$ are all considered independent, real parameters.

```
Solve[Join[eqns, cons], {a, b}]                  (*   {}   *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful explanation!

Comment: @Akku14 - Yep, I messed up.

Answer (score 2):

```
eqs0 = Subtract @@@ {a^2 == X, (a + b)^2 == Y, {a + I b}^2 == Z}

ceRe = ComplexExpand[Re[eqs0 /. b -> b1 + I b2], 
         TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

ceIm = ComplexExpand[Im[eqs0 /. b -> b1 + I b2], 
         TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

red = Reduce[
  Flatten[{Thread[ceRe == 0], Thread[DeleteCases[ceIm, 0] == 0]}, 
1], {a, b1, b2}, Reals];

TraditionalForm[
  red //. Or -> 
  Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

Or LogicalExpand/Reduce it to have no cross dependence of a,b1,b2

```
TraditionalForm[
  Reduce[LogicalExpand[red]] //. 
    Or -> Composition[(Column[#, Right, 
   Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Your solution is brilliant.  But I can only accept one answer. Thank you all the same. I learned a lot from your solution!

Comment: If you appreciate it, it would be nice to upvote.

Comment: yes, already done. Thanks.